# How to click a JavaScript confirm popup via excel vba

Tags: vba, dom

I am using the InternetExplorer object to interact with a web page, filling out a form and all that. At one point, after clicking a button on a page a Dialog box pops up asking to confirm the operation. How do I click the OK button in the popup?

The relevant JavaScript and HTML is:

```
function CheckMakeCurr() 
{
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to set the\n "Last Rebalance Date" to today?')) 
        { return true; }
    else
        { return false; }
};
```

...

```
<INPUT onclick="return CheckMakeCurr()" class=button type=submit value="Make Current" name=updaterebaldt>
```

The Excel vba code is:

```
Dim oInput As IHTMLInputElement

' Initialize oInput.
...

' Click oInput.
oInput.click

' The confirm box comes up. What now?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you click the link, remove the `onclick` handler which triggers the popup:

```
oInput.onclick = ""
oInput.click
```