# How to click a button that appears after a buttonclick?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I deal with this code. Here I want to click on a button but then a box appears that I am not able to deal with.

```
 <input type="image" name="senden" src="/img/misc/b_go.gif" alt="Go" 
  title="Go" value="submit" 
  onclick="return confirm('Willst du wirklich jetzt deine Aufstellung und Taktik festlegen?');">
```

First, button click:

```
Set ButtonAufstellung = objIE.document.getElementsByName("senden")(0)
    ButtonAufstellung.Click
```

Second, the popup appears and I get asked if I am really sure. I can click <kbd>Ok</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> but I always want to click <kbd>Ok</kbd>. I could not find any solution that works.

I tried some solutions, but was not able to implement them.

Here somebody had a simillar problem but I did not understand: [How to click a JavaScript confirm popup via excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424332/how-to-click-a-javascript-confirm-popup-via-excel-vba)

Edit:

Solutions that do not work:

```
Element.onclick = "Submit()"
Element.onclick = "True"
Element.onclick = "OK"
Element.onclick = "SendKeys{ENTER}"
```

Comment: maybe instead of clicking the button...call the underlying javascript that the button calls (after the confirmation)...example on how to call javascript form vba - http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?9690-Solved-call-a-javascript-function

Comment: It did not work.I tried different approaches. Pressing Enter  did not work either.  I think there must be some elegant way to do it.             Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", "Sub_Enter"
Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "Sub_Enter"

Comment: whats the javascript look like that has the button?...the buttons whole tag

Comment: I would prefer a solution that does not change any java, because i need to save and this does not work then. it must be a solution that, where vba is able to see the popup and click the button.

Comment: Vba is single threaded...I think your thread will be waiting on the dialog...not 100 percent sure but...that might be a challenge to the approach you want to achieve

Comment: Could you please share the webpage URL, and also what is the final goal? Do you need to retrieve some data from the page? If so, have you tried XHR instead of IE?

Comment: Easiest fix is to overwrite the `window.confirm` function with one which just returns `true`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228144/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-vba/30229398#30229398